# Como solucionar o erro de prepare desse script?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, pdo, prepared-statement

Estou a 2 horas procurando uma solução para [***este problema***][1]. Estou começando um curso de ***Loja virtual com PHP*** e o erro é o seguinte: ele fala que estou tentando dar um ***prepare*** num objeto não instanciado.

A lógica é a seguinte: ele fez a classe de ***CRUD*** e está instaciando-a por enquanto, só para exemplificar, dentro do arquivo da classe ***ConnDB***. Porque está ocorrendo este erro?

Dei ***highlight_file*** nos arquivos para que possam ver o script e o erro.

```
// autoload - para chamar todas as classes instanciadas
function __autoload($class) { require_once "{$class}.class.php"; }

// final - pode instanciar mas nÃ£o pode extender
// abstract - pode extender mas nÃ£o pode instanciar 
abstract class ConnDB
{
    private static $conexao;

    private function setConn()
    {
        is_null(self::$conexao) ? 
                self::$conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql.axitech.com.br;dbname=dbname", "user", "pass") :
                self::$conexao;
    }

    public function getConn()
    {
        return $this->setConn();
    }
}

$inserir = new CRUD;
$inserir->insert('user', 'user=?, email=?, cidade=?', array('yesmarcos', 'mvnpereira@gmail.com', 'Campo Grande'));
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/axitech/www/mylojavirtual/require/class/CRUD.class.php on line 11

Comment: Parece que sua conexão não está sendo retornada em  `setConn()` da um `return self::$conexao` já deve corrigir o primeiro erro.

Comment: xD o user e senha da pergunta, se não a galera vai acessar

Comment: No outro arquivo faça o include `ConnDB`

Comment: Obrigado @rray realmente faltava o ***return*** no ***is_null***

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Se possível, responsa sua própria pergunta aqui e marque como aceita, para que outros possam encontrar mais facilmente a solução para problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 1):

Bom pessoal, o único problema naquele caso ali é que eu estava me esquecendo de retornar o resultado da conexão em `setConn` e o `getConn` por sua vez estava retornando **nada** já que o método `setConn` também não estava retornando nada. Ficou assim:

```
// autoload - para chamar todas as classes instanciadas
function __autoload($class) { require_once "{$class}.class.php"; }

// final - pode instanciar mas nÃ£o pode extender
// abstract - pode extender mas nÃ£o pode instanciar 
abstract class ConnDB
{
    private static $conexao;

    private function setConn()
    {
         return  // <----- O erro era aqui          
         is_null(self::$conexao) ? 
                self::$conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql.axitech.com.br;dbname=dbname", "user", "pass") :
                self::$conexao;
    }

    public function getConn()
    {
        return $this->setConn();
    }
}

$inserir = new CRUD;
$inserir->insert('user', 'user=?, email=?, cidade=?', array('yesmarcos', 'mvnpereira@gmail.com', 'Campo Grande'));
```